# Interacting Between Wallet Address and Mainnet Contract Address

Tags: web3js, nft

I'm trying to understand how a wallet address can interact with a mainnet contract address. Can anyone provide some insight on this? I'm particularly interested in learning about the technical details and potential challenges involved in this process.

https://www.oklink.com/zh-cn/okc/tx/0x7E5C5597254F7694C7380A0E499564A3F9364F52C53D5B50997F19DA9C79FDD2

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The process roughly:

1. A wallet has a private key
2. A raw transaction is created (usually by a website) which wants to interact with a contract. The transaction contains the contract's address and various other data needed to interact with the contract.
3. This transaction is presented for the user to sign, usually via a browser wallet
4. User signs the transaction, which is then broadcasted to the blockchain
5. The transaction is picked up by validator nodes and included in a block. Any contract state changes performed by the transaction are part of the transaction, and anyone who wants to read the blockchain needs to analyze this transaction to update their own view of the blockchain accordingly

There are lots of potential issues in the chain, but here is the overall picture. Please post more detailed questions (or search for existing ones) if you have specific questions in mind.

Answer (score 1):

For interacting with smart contracts, each wallet need to approve transactions and in this approval get access contract to do something.

For example if you want to interact with an DEX(decentralized exchange) and swap your tokens , you need to allow contract for sending your tokens into contract address.
Imagine you have some USDC and want to swap with LINK, for doing this, you must approve some amount of your USDC token, in USDC contract address and give an address to USDC contract address which says you want to these amount of token to which address?? this address must be DEX contract address it means you you allowed DEX contract to can send your tokens in USDC contract, after that you can send your tokens.

This way an wallet can interact with an contract address